# Copy data from one folder to another inside a AWS bucket automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to copy files from one folder to another inside the same bucket.

- I have two folders Actual and Backup
- As soon as new files comes to actual folder i want a way so that it immediately gets copied to Backup folder.

Comment: Please read [ask] and show us what you've tried as a [mre]. However, your best bet would be an S3-PUT-event triggered lambda.

Comment: Ok, so create a Lambda to do the work?  Or, use Same-Region Replication to have S3 copy to a backup bucket.  Or, enable versioning and use old versions of objects if you need to.

Comment: @baduker Hello, I tried the event way but i wanted to know If we have some option at the folder level to do a copy similar to what a event does. As i don't want to use a separate lambda for this work.

Comment: There's no such thing as *an option at the folder level*. S3 event notification + lambda.

Comment: You can't configure S3 replication for the same bucket. The best solution is the one proposed below

Answer (score 1):

What you need are [S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html). With these you can trigger a lambda function when a new item is put, then if it is put with one prefix, write the same object to the other prefix.

It is also worth noting that, though it is functionally as it seems, S3 doesn't really have directories; just objects. So you are just creating the same object as `/Actual/some-file` with key `/Backup/some-file` . It just looks like there is a directory because files `/Actual/some-file` and `/Actual/other-file` share a prefix `/Actual/`.

Comment: Hello, I tried the event way but I wanted to know If we have some option at the folder level to do a copy similar to what an event does as I don't want to use a separate lambda for this work.

Comment: There is not that I know of. Like a commenter above said, you can use replication in another bucket, but what you describe is not possible because like I say in my answer, s3 doesn't have folders.